# How to debug MySQL replication error 1049?

Tags: sql, mysql, database-replication

I had a working MySQL master-slave replication that recently I've noticed it's been failed few mins ago.

Here's the result of `SHOW SLAVE STATUS\G`:

```
*************************** 1. row ***************************
               Slave_IO_State: Waiting for source to send event
                  Master_Host: 185.128.xxx.xxx
                  Master_User: replica
                  Master_Port: 3306
                Connect_Retry: 60
              Master_Log_File: mysql-bin.000002
          Read_Master_Log_Pos: 2456753
               Relay_Log_File: mysql-relay-bin.000003
                Relay_Log_Pos: 1595182
        Relay_Master_Log_File: mysql-bin.000002
             Slave_IO_Running: Yes
            Slave_SQL_Running: No
              Replicate_Do_DB:
          Replicate_Ignore_DB:
           Replicate_Do_Table:
       Replicate_Ignore_Table:
      Replicate_Wild_Do_Table:
  Replicate_Wild_Ignore_Table:
                   Last_Errno: 1049
                   Last_Error: Coordinator stopped because there were error(s) in the worker(s). The most recent failure being: Worker 1 failed executing transaction 'ANONYMOUS' at source log mysql-bin.000002, end_log_pos 1595341. See error log and/or performance_schema.replication_applier_status_by_worker table for more details about this failure or others, if any.
                 Skip_Counter: 0
          Exec_Master_Log_Pos: 1594966
              Relay_Log_Space: 2457347
              Until_Condition: None
               Until_Log_File:
                Until_Log_Pos: 0
           Master_SSL_Allowed: No
           Master_SSL_CA_File:
           Master_SSL_CA_Path:
              Master_SSL_Cert:
            Master_SSL_Cipher:
               Master_SSL_Key:
        Seconds_Behind_Master: NULL
Master_SSL_Verify_Server_Cert: No
                Last_IO_Errno: 0
                Last_IO_Error:
               Last_SQL_Errno: 1049
               Last_SQL_Error: Coordinator stopped because there were error(s) in the worker(s). The most recent failure being: Worker 1 failed executing transaction 'ANONYMOUS' at source log mysql-bin.000002, end_log_pos 1595341. See error log and/or performance_schema.replication_applier_status_by_worker table for more details about this failure or others, if any.
  Replicate_Ignore_Server_Ids:
             Master_Server_Id: 1
                  Master_UUID: 42e23b0a-9fec-11ea-a6a6-00163e051c80
             Master_Info_File: mysql.slave_master_info
                    SQL_Delay: 0
          SQL_Remaining_Delay: NULL
      Slave_SQL_Running_State:
           Master_Retry_Count: 86400
                  Master_Bind:
      Last_IO_Error_Timestamp:
     Last_SQL_Error_Timestamp: 230810 13:58:36
               Master_SSL_Crl:
           Master_SSL_Crlpath:
           Retrieved_Gtid_Set:
            Executed_Gtid_Set:
                Auto_Position: 0
         Replicate_Rewrite_DB:
                 Channel_Name:
           Master_TLS_Version:
       Master_public_key_path:
        Get_master_public_key: 0
            Network_Namespace:
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
```

Based on some research, the error code `1049` means "Unknown Database"; But honestly I have no idea how to debug?

What should I do now? Should I `STOP SLAVE`? And `START SLAVE` again? Or how to know which database is called that has been unknown?

---

Configuration on the Master:

```
bind-address = 185.128.xxx.xxx
server-id = 1
log_bin = /var/log/mysql/mysql-bin.log
binlog_do_db = my_db_name
```

Configuration on the Slave:

```
server-id = 2
max_binlog_size = 100M
# log_bin = /var/log/mysql/mysql-bin.log
binlog_do_db = my_db_name
relay-log = /var/log/mysql/mysql-relay-bin.log
```

Comment: Please post the configuration on the Master and the configuration on the Slave, only the replication related part

Comment: On the slave `binlog_do_db`  should be `replicate_do_db = my_db_name` . In the master side comment the binlog_do_db  and  use MIXED format. As per the replication you need to reset the replication, dump the db from the master and restore to the slave.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @ErgestBasha. Just are you sure I have to change the configuration? You know, it was working well until few mins ago. Also, to change the things you mentioned, should I need to stop replica before that?

Comment: Also @ErgestBasha, I've already set the Mixed format by this query `SET GLOBAL binlog_format = "MIXED"; `

Comment: `binlog-do-db` makes the master write statements only  for the specified DB into binary log if none specified  it will write the logs for each db(schema).
`replicate-do-db` makes the slave just read statements from the relay log, that are for the specified DB . *should I need to stop replica before that?* the more important thing is to dump the db and get the master position this can be done by using `mysqldump -u root -p --master-data=1  db_name> /home/your_user/db_name.sql` . See [master-data](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_master-data).

Comment: See [master-data](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_master-data). On the slave you need to execute `stop slave ; reset slave; ` then import the backup and finally  `start slave`. I can give an answer with all the mentioned details if you want

Comment: @ErgestBasha: "On the slave binlog_do_db should be....use MIXED format". Really? Why?

Comment: @symcbean *Mixed mode switches between the ROW and STATEMENT, using whichever is most efficient or safe*. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-replication-excerpt/8.0/en/replication-sbr-rbr.html . Personally I choose MIXED

Comment: I know what it does, I was wondering why you thought the OP needed to do this, and to only replicate a single database?

Comment: @symcbean from my experience I was thinking the worst scenarios. For example if statement format was used and the OP has more than one schema. If the current schema  is `schemma1` and OP execute `update schemma2.tbl ` you know the replication will break.

Comment: Your scenario is predicated on the replication having been configured to exclude schema1 - we don't know that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how to know which database is called that has been unknown?

That at least is easy:

```
echo "show databases;" | mysql -h dbhost1 >dbsOnDb1
echo "show databases;" | mysql -h dbhost2 >dbsOnDb2
diff dbsOnDb1 dbsOnDb2
```

(on Linux/Unix)

Then just create the database on the slave and restart the slave process.

But you really should investigate *why* the CREATE DATABASE statement was not in the binlog. Have  --replicate-do-db or --replicate-ignore-db been chaged recently? There is a weird scoping thing where if (for example) you are excluding the database named 'local' and you do this:

```
USE local;
CREATE DATABASE newdb;
```

Then the statement will not be replicated as it was executed in the local database (even though its effect is outside that database).

Comment: I did what you said, now the error code changed to `1146`. As you know, it's complaining about *table doesn't exist*. You know, I just wanted to replicate one database, that's why I just got a backup only from that one database using `mysqldump` and imported it on the slave server. Now apparently there is a dependency between other databases. Should I start over?

Comment: Might be simpler to resync via backup at this point. But you still need to work out how the situation arose. The answer should be in your general log on the master.

Comment: One thing, isn't there an approach to visualize the exact query/statement that causes the slave to fail? You know, the current error code is `1146` which means the table does not exist. Ok, but what table from which db? how to find it?

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqlbinlog.html - the file and position are reported in `SHOW SLAVE STATUS`

Comment: I've run this command `mysqlbinlog mysql-relay-bin.000003 --start-position=1595181 --stop-position=1595183`, but it printed some strange texts, do you understand anything of [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xoTob.png)?

Comment: No - possibly a framing error. Your original post above reported the issue @ 1595182 - IIRC these are byte offset not logical records.

Comment: The problem resolved by stopping the replica, running `SET GLOBAL SQL_SLAVE_SKIP_COUNTER = 1; `, and starting it again ..! Not sure what was the exact issue. What I've done is ok? Or I'm at the risk now because of skipping a change to be applied on the replica?

Comment: @MartinAJ *The problem resolved by stopping the replica, running SET GLOBAL SQL_SLAVE_SKIP_COUNTER = 1;* the problem is skipped not solved. If you haven't found the issue you cant be sure. Safest way would be to do a resync